# How can I connect an external hard drive to a Windows 95 computer?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, data-transfer, windows-95

I have an *old* Windows 95 computer at home. It's a Dell Dimension XPS D266. I've decided to get rid of it, but first I want to get all of the data off of it. It has a 16 GB hard drive, and I have a new 3 TB external hard drive that I thought I could connect to it. The external hard drive is a Western Digital My Book. I'd prefer not to take out the drive and connect it up.

Is it possible to connect the external hard drive to my Windows 95 computer? The computer *does* have a working USB port, and it has "USB drivers" - though I'm assuming I'd need to install a new driver to it.

If I can't connect this to the computer, I'd use a flash drive to connect to it. How can I identify what driver I will need for Windows 95 to recognize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally... you don't - I forsee *multiple* issues that might block you from what you're doing. It would be significantly less painful to boot a minimal linux distro. If you must...

There's 'generic' USB drivers for [windows 98](http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/usbmsd98.php), but none I can find for windows 95. You will need to find something that has *specific* drivers for windows 95 it to work.

Even if you *did* get it to work - a 3tb drive is likely to be too large for windows 95 to read ([It dosen't support anything bigger than 32gb](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Hard-Disk-Drives-Capacity-Limits/482/2)).

Its also likely to be USB 1.1, which is *painfully* slow

I'd transfer the files over a network - I'm *guessing* windows file sharing is still [compatible](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-9598me/wxpwin9x.html). Assuming it has a NIC, even if its limited to 100mbps or even fast ethernet, it may end up being faster than USB.